# How to remove unused xml , java code from android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, optimization, android-xml, android-resources

I am trying to optimizing my android project by removing unused xml and java code from android studio and i am searching for such shortcuts which can be helpful for me to achieve the optimization.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried proguard ?

Answer (score 5):

Android studio provides you with set of refactoring and code optimization tools, where you can remove unused resources and variables, optimize imports.

**Just right click on your project's root folder > Refactor > Remove Unused Resources...**

And also same way **Right click > Optimize imports**

Also you can try code analysis feature of Lint ...
**Right click on project's root folder > Analyze > Inspect code** 
this finds code smells and gives you warning for different aspects in your code.

Check the following link to read more about [Lint](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html)

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio :

1. Go to Analyze -> Inspect code
2. Unused xmls will be in Android > Lint > Performance
   [image]